# How could I line up images on the same line?

Tags: html, css, image

I need help aligning 5 images on the same lines using HTML5 and CSS3!

I have tried using other methods (which I have forgotten so I can't leave an example) but they don't work. I don't want to use absolute positioning because I want my website to be as mobile friendly as possible.

Could someone reply with some code of how to do this?

Comment: could you show your attempt? show your markup. Anyway by default images already align themselves in the same line since they are inline-replaced elements and default vertical-align is baseline

Answer (score 0):

```
display: inline-flex;
flex-direction: row;
```

That should work.

Here a good source of information: [Basic concepts of flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)

Answer (score 0):

Use Flexbox (ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

See example in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oew4a8xn/

Comment: Depending on the rest of your code (or what you're trying to achieve overall), you might want to consider the Grid Layout as well -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout